# How to make it so the data in an arraylist is unchangable once its been added in

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2 classes, one class Human which is a simple object containing a String for a name and an int for age. My other class has two parameters, its own name and an array of type Human.

```
public class Human {

private String name;
private int age;


public Human (String currName, int currAge) 
{

    name = currName;
    age = currAge;

}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public int getAge() 
{
    return age;
}

public void setName(String newName) 
{
    name = newName;
}

public void setAge (int newAge) 
{
    age = newAge;
}

}
```

And

```
import java.util.*;


public class AListCopyTest {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Human> HumanList = new ArrayList<>();


public AListCopyTest(String currName, ArrayList<Human> HList) 
{
    name = currName;
    HumanList = HList;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<Human> getListofHumans(){
    return HumanList;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public void setListofHumans(ArrayList<Human> newList){
    HumanList = newList;
}





/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    System.out.println("Testing Array Creation");

    Human One = new Human("John", 10);
    Human Two = new Human("Mary", 20);
    Human Three = new Human("Steve", 30);
    Human Four = new Human("Paul", 55);

    ArrayList<Human> MainList = new ArrayList<>();

    MainList.add(One);
    MainList.add(Two);
    MainList.add(Three);
    MainList.add(Four);

    AListCopyTest Trial1 = new AListCopyTest("List of Humans", MainList);

    //System.out.println(Trial1);
    for (Human count: MainList) 
    {
        System.out.println("Person Name: " + count.getName() + "    Person Age: " + count.getAge());
    }


    System.out.println("\n" + "\n");
    //Now need to make it so ArrayList is unaffected by what comes next
    //Effectively need to make it so the print happens after the changes are made, yet prints info from before changes
    One.setName("Peter");
    Two.setAge(33);
    Three.setAge(50);
    Three.setName("Carlos");
    Four.setName("Jane");

    for (Human count: MainList) 
    {
        System.out.println("Person Name: " + count.getName() + "    Person Age: " + count.getAge());
    }



}

}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that once a Human is added to the array, it is effectively "locked in" with arguments it has for its lifetime, so that it can't be changed by any of my setters so when it prints again the output is the same as the first time its run.

I know I could just have a copy constructor create a duplicate before I make any changes and then just print that out instead, but thats not what I need. I need it so that I can print from that exact same arraylist and get the same results. How would I go about this, exactly? I've read about making a List unmutable, but I still want to be able to add onto the list if need be, just unable to change what is already on there.

If needed, this is what my output currently looks like:

```
Testing Array Creation
Person Name: John    Person Age: 10
Person Name: Mary    Person Age: 20
Person Name: Steve    Person Age: 30
Person Name: Paul    Person Age: 55



Person Name: Peter    Person Age: 10
Person Name: Mary    Person Age: 33
Person Name: Carlos    Person Age: 50
Person Name: Jane    Person Age: 55
```

Comment: Unclear. You want to create a list and add items to it, but not allow to remove the items, change the item in the list position and change the content/data of the item?

Comment: I want to create a list and be able to add to it, and then once an item is in there have it be 'final' so to speak. So yes, I want to make it so the contents cannot be changed once put in. I suppose removal would also be possible, but is unnecessary for my purposes. Essentially, I want whatever I put into my list to be 'saved' and not be altered by anything else once its in the List

Comment: Then you don't care about the list, only the objects in the list. The list is completely irrelevant. What you're looking for is to make your objects *immutable*. Try [here](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=java+how+to+make+an+object+immutable&gws_rd=cr&ei=yH26WKbZC8mYgAal-ov4Bw).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to not create setters, just create a constructor in which you cant create the arraylist. Plus create an addItem method that adds items to the arraylist instead of adding a setter.

Comment: Well, yes, having no setters at all would of course make the items unchangable, but thats not really what I'm going for here. I need to make it so that regardless of any setters attempt to make changes to the item, but only in the array itself. And I need to use the default add method as well. For example, if after printing everything above and having there be no change, I'd still want to be able to call up the name of Human One and have it return Peter, the updated name, if this is at all possible. I just don't want it to change whats in the arraylist.